# How to do the equivalent of rpm -qf in AIX? (Which package does this file belong to?)

Tags: rpm, package-management, aix

So. I have a binary in /opt/freeware/bin in an AIX PPC machine whose origin I don't know. It could be an RPM -- most open-source AIX RPMs install in /opt/freeware. But no such luck. It must have been from an installp package (.bff). How can I discover which of the installed packages, if any, contains this file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lslpp -w <file>` looks right, according to the unix rosetta stone: http://bhami.com/rosetta.html#software

Answer (score 2):

I believe the command you want is `lslpp` (with the `-w` flag).